# Returning Array from ActiveX component to JavaScript

Tags: arrays, activex, return-value, javascript

I have an ActiveX component (which I did not write and have no control over). It has several methods I want to use, which return arrays. Every time I attempt to do something of the sort:

```
var arrayValue = axObj.methodWhichReturnsArray();
```

the arrayValue object is undefined. The component provider tells me that I should not be having any of the problems I'm describing. I do perform a null check which it passes (meaning the axObj is not null).

The component provider, however, is using JScript, not JavaScript, in his example, which goes something like

```
var arrayVar = axComponent.getListAsArray();
var theArray = (new VBArray(arrayVar)).toArray();
alert(theArray[0]);
alert(theArray[1]);
alert(theArray[2]);
```

But again, I am using JavaScript (and have never used JScript) so am not sure of what the difference is...

(And I am a weathered Java veteran, so all of it is frustrating.)

Thank you!

Comment: What browser(s) are you trying this on?

Comment: If you are in IE, you *are* using JScript and not JavaScript (which is Mozilla's implementation). The VBArray constructor should be available.

Comment: p. sure that "JScript" is just the name Microsoft uses for the interpreter that runs what everybody else calls "Javascript"

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the responses!  

I'm using IE.  So if my tag is <script language="JavaScript">, in IE, that's really the same as <script language="JScript">?  I had no idea, really.  

I've never had to use ActiveX components before, a whole new world for me (coming from EJB and Java middleware - think my brain is hemorrhaging).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JScript is Microsofts version of Javascript from "back in the day" and is still going strong.

First question has to be where are you trying to use it? In the browser? Intranet? IE only? Server-side?

JScript is not available in anything other than IE or on a IIS Server or MS desktop machine so I hope you are running it on one of the above.

JScript has a special function in it for converting VBScript arrays to JScript arrays (as they are stored differently) which is the VBArray function in your code.

You might be able to get around this by using an JScript Enumerator http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ch9zb09(VS.85).aspx

Something like (although untested):

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var e = new Enumerator(fso.Drives);
var myArray = [];
do {
 myArray.push( e.item() );
 e.moveNext();
} while ( !e.atEnd() );

document.write( myArray.join( "<li>" );
```